# How to display html table single column into multiple columns?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a simple table with one big column. I want to display this single columns into multiple columns. Currently I have like as follows:

```
Column
a
a
a
a
a
a
```

I need something like:

```
      Column
a     a       a
a     a       a
```

My code is as follows:

```
<table>        
    <thead>Details</thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How I can do that without changing the table structure?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLjmpvuz/

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: two rows `<tr>` each one having three cells `<td>`. That's the answer.

Comment: adding more td's to each tr or what? http://jsfiddle.net/wLjmpvuz/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this without changing the table structure as requested, you would need to use CSS that prevents normal table display and instead implements a “simulated table”. This can be done by turning the `tr` elements to inline blocks floated to the left but floating cleared after each three `tr` elements. This won’t work on old versions of IE. Example:

```
table {
  display: block;
}
tr {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   border: solid 1px;
   width: 4em;
}
td {
   display: inline;
}
tr:nth-child(3n+1) {
   clear: left;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/wh66x2kv/). Note that such simulated tables have many limitations. You cannot let browsers allocate column widths (as there are no real columns); instead you need to set the element widths to create an impression of columns. You cannot make adjacent borders collapse as in a table, so setting borders is more work.

You could keep the HTML markup, but not the table structure, by using JavaScript code that constructs a new `table` element, with three cells in a row, cell contents taken from the original table, and then replaces the original table with the newly created one.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not as clear as water but if I understand you, you want a nested table

Something like this:

```
<table>        
    <thead>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Column2
        </th>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>a</td>
                            <td>a</td>
                            <td>a</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>a</td>
                            <td>a</td>
                            <td>a</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                Other Column Data
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/wLjmpvuz/6/

In case you need just a flat table should be without the nested table:

```
<table>        
    <thead>Details</thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Fiddler:  http://jsfiddle.net/wLjmpvuz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't change table structure ? each  is a new line. Try this

```
<table>        
    <thead>Details</thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>

            <td>a</td>

            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>

            <td>a</td>

            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>

            <td>a</td>

            <td>a</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem.   http://jsfiddle.net/wLjmpvuz/8/

```
<table>        
<thead>Details</thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
         <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
         <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
         <td>a</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```